# How to get auth code from MSAL react login

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, msal-react, msal

I am using msal React and doing Microsoft login. I need the auth code so that I can send that to the backend and the backend can use that to get the refresh token and all.

Right now when I do login in network tab I see the code, refresh token, and all. But in the login response, I do not get a refresh token and as code I get undefined.

How can I proceed further? Your help will be much appreciated

I tried going through various blogs and documents, but couldn't figure out how to do this.

I am trying to build an auth flow and I expect either I get a refresh token at the client side and send that to the backend or get an auth code from the client side which I send to the backend and then the backend use that to create a refresh token.

Comment: In my humble opinion, you'd better to give up this idea `I need the auth code so that I can send that to the backend and the backend can use that to get the refresh token and all`... these access token and refresh token should be obtained in your react app instead of the backend app.